# Как сделать кнопки автоскролла на странице?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css, php

Всем привет! Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей, как сделать висячие кнопки скролла (вверх\вниз) на страницу сайта, при том чтобы скролл работал только при удерживании нажатой кнопки, и не срабатывал автоматом в самый верх или самый низ страницы? 
Прбовал переделать скрипт на jquery (автоскролл на верх страницы), пока безуспешно

Comment: Удерживать нужно кнопку на странице или на клавиатуре?

Answer (score 2):

Если я всё правильно понял, то посмотрите [такой примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9Q9Hz/). По крайней мере, возьмете за основу и заточите под себя.